# I'm having trouble installing sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server

This is what happens when I try to use sql server (img 1) [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpfcC.png)

I tried googling the solution and still can't figure out what's wrong. I've tried reinstalling multiple times and even wiped my hard drive to reinstall it. It does not let me install without windows authentication.

[Empty services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dOZh.png)
There is nothing inside of the services and network configuration. Does know how to fix it by using windows authentication? It doesn't matter what I enter in the user name it always gives me the same error.

Comment: what is the status of sql server service

Comment: @Michael Is your SQL SERVER AGENT Running?

Comment: @TheGameiswar There are no Items to show.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas I'm not sure what you mean by 'agent'

Comment: @Michael Run > services.msc
check wheather the service is running.

Comment: check status in windows services

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas No it isn't running

Comment: try repair first and resinstalling.check this link for more details :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108899/sql-server-services-empty-in-sql-server-configuration as well as this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2492/why-is-sql-server-configuration-manager-missing-services/

Answer (score 0):

Run services.msc

Start all services for SQL server including SQLEXPRESS it will work

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I start the services? I can't find them on this list.

Comment: @Michael Do you see SQL SERVER in Services?

Comment: No it isn't there =(